# Assigning DefaultValue in ASP.NET for SelectParameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

I'm trying to assign **default value to the user that are currently login,** for them to view their profile.

Here is the datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataProfile" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT username, email, studIC, password, studGuardian, studPhone, studAddress, studClass, studName FROM RegStudents WHERE (username LIKE @username + '%')" UpdateCommand="UPDATE RegStudents SET username = @username, password = @password, studName = @studName, studClass = @studClass, studAddress = @studAddress, studPhone = @studPhone, studGuardian = @studGuardian, studIC = @studIC WHERE (username LIKE @username + '%')">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue="@username" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="password" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studClass" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studAddress" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studPhone" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studGuardian" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="studIC" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
  public partial class ProfilePage : System.Web.UI.Page {

     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
          SqlDataProfile.SelectParameters["username"].DefaultValue =User.Identity.Name; 
                }
```

When I set the default value into existing username as below, it totally works but doesn't work with the code above.

```
<asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String" DefaultValue="amanda123" />
```

Comment: You could delete the `DefaultValue` attribute from Parameter tag. `<asp:Parameter Name="username" Type="String">` anyhow you are assigning this through codebehind.

Comment: Thanks I did that, but still, it isn't working :\